# Mac OS (Mojave) - Pycharm backend : TkAgg not working, graphs are blank

Tags: python-3.x, matplotlib, backend

I am fairly new to python (and Stackflow) so apologies if this is a repost. I am currently run Pycharm on my iMac (with Mac OS Mojave), python install from Anaconda.

I am having some issues with Matplotlib as everytime I plot a graph I don't see anything. The backend currently uses TkAgg. I googled the issue and came across many links and tried to change the backend in matplotlibrc, but that just gave me errors.

It is Mojave specific problem? I have another Mac with High Sierra (which uses MacOSX in the backend) and Matplotlib runs fine on it. I tried changing the backend on my iMac to MacOSX but that doesn't work. Any help will be really appreciated as I have already spend more than 3-4 hours (in vain!) to fix the problem

If I need to change the backend in matplotlibrc, could you advise what should I be using?

thanks,
PK

Comment: I doubt the information here is specific enough to allow anyone to grasp the problem and eventually be able to help.

Comment: thanks, unsure what else I could add.  I have read in most of the links that if plt.show() doesn't bring up anything then either uninstall and reinstall Matplotlib (using pip uninstall/ install Matplotlib) or change the backend in the matplotlibrc file (in the /.matplotlib folder), I have tried doing both. (Tired changing backend from TkAgg to MacOSX).

Comment: We don't know your system, we don't know what you do, which code you run, how you run it. You don't tell which errors you got. So to start, what happens if you run `python -c "import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1,2]); plt.show()"`? Then what happens if you change the backend, `python -c "import matplotlib; matplotlib.use("TkAgg"); import matplotlib.pyplot as plt; plt.plot([1,2]); plt.show()"`? Usually, you would either get a figure window, or an error.

Comment: ok thanks, so if I run your code, I get no error (I see "Process finished with exit code 0"), and I see a figure window which is blank.                                                                   If I change the backend I still get the same output (no error and a blank figure window).

Comment: btw I tried changing the backend to MacOSX and got this error (RuntimeError: Python is not installed as a framework. The Mac OS X backend will not be able to function correctly if Python is not installed as a framework. See the Python documentation for more information on installing Python as a framework on Mac OS X. Please either reinstall Python as a framework, or try one of the other backends. If you are using (Ana)Conda please install python.app and replace the use of 'python' with 'pythonw'. ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you use virtualenv in Mojave, you have to install matplotliv (v1.3.1) at virtualenv. ** NOT VERSION 2.2.3 **. so, try the below command (btw, in your code, 'TkAgg' is needless):

$pip install --no-cache-dir matplotlib==1.3.1

everything will be fine.

Comment: I had the same problem but this didn't work for me. Switching to ipython and running the magic command `%matplotlib` did work.